# jetty runner web app not recognizing jstl tags?

Tags: jstl, jetty

It completely ignores all jstl tags and never gives out any erros. On the other hand, maven jetty:start works.  any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Define "ignores". Is there a JSTL library?

Comment: there is jstl and standard libs. "ignores" means not trying to parse tags.